Asymptotic behaviour of connecting probability of two point in square Bernoulli percolation
Consider Bernoulli percolation with open probability $p$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, I want to study the asympotic behaviour of probability $$\mathbb{P}_p\left((0,0) \text{ connect to } (0,n) \text{ by a open path }\right).$$
For $p<\frac{1}{2}$, clearly we can see this probability is of exponential decay, and this is sharp up to a constant. For $p=\frac{1}{2}$, we can see this probability is $\mathrm{O}(n^{-c})$ but I don't know if we can get better bound. For $p>\frac{1}{2}$, by square root trick we have
$$ \max_{0\leq k\leq n} \mathbb{P}\left((0,0) \text{ connected to } (k,n)\right)\geq 1-\mathbb{P}\left( \text{upper side of }[-n,n]^2 \text{ not connect to } \infty
 \right)^{1/n}, $$
then I have no idea about it.
I want to know if there is any reference for this problem? Or can anyone give some estimate about it?
Any help is appreciated.

I resume you mean bond (not site) percolation, for which $p_{cr}=1/2$.
For $p>1/2$ you are in the supercitical regime, so each given site belongs to a (unique) infinite cluster with some probability $\theta(p)$.
The probability that two distinct points are connected but not via this cluster, decays to zero. Hence the answer should be $\theta(p)^2$.
You may check this or this.
